# My Expect script is jumping when read file

Tags: bash, expect

I make script, use expect to sent all command in file line by line. But the result is not all command in file are sent to terminal. need your suggestion what need to improve

bellow is command script.

```
set saddress [lrange $argv 0 0]
spawn ssh Rd@$saddress
expect "password:"
send "AAAA\r"
#expect "#"
#send "terminal length 0\r"
set namafile [lindex $argv 1]
set f [ open "$namafile" ]
set commands [ split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach cmd $commands {
expect {
"#" { send -- "$cmd\r" }
"No]:" { send -- "Y\r" }
}
#sleep 2
}

expect "#"
send "logout\r"
```

content file that need to be read and execute as below:

```
==
conf t
xgw
pgw
release-subscriber-imsi 510092008527215
release-subscriber-imsi 510092008497549
release-subscriber-imsi 510092008497291
release-subscriber-imsi 510092008479295
end
write
```

execute script result is success but shown as log only sent 2 release command to terminal instead 4 command, why this can happen ?

```bash
/usr/bin/expect kickuserxGW30.txt 172.31.201.98 userbandunginxgw30.txt > /resultkick/xGW30.txt &
```

Result  log file:

```
30#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CTRL/Z.
30(config)#xgw
30(config-xgw)#pgw
30(config-xgw-pgw)#release-subscriber-imsi 510092008527215
Release online subscriber according to IMSI information. Are you sure to continue? [Yes/No]:Y
%Code 170002: Error, no user found! 

SPJKTZ030(config-xgw-pgw)#release-subscriber-imsi 510092008497291
Release online subscriber according to IMSI information. Are you sure to continue? [Yes/No]:Y
%Code 170002: Error, no user found! 

30(config-xgw-pgw)#end
30#write
Write DB OK!
Building configuration...
.[OK].
30#
```

Answer (score 0):

> why this can happen ?

It is programmed that way in the `foreach` loop; in the loop cycle when `cmd` was the first `release-subscriber-imsi`, the expected `#` arrived, the release command was executed and the loop proceeded to the next cycle, then with the second `release-subscriber-imsi`; now the expected `No]:` arrives, `Y` is sent, but nothing is done with the `cmd`, so it is not sent, and the loop proceeds.

The command `exp_continue` put at the end of the `No]:` body should rectify this.

Comment: thanks @Armali. after modify this part '"No]:" { send -- "Y\r" ; exp_continue }' work exactly as I want.